# Sim900A cannot configure to use SSL

Tags: gsm, at-command

I'm using a gsm module Sim900A. I want to make a web request to a https api but it doesn't work.

Anything I write in the line `AT+HTTPSSL` gives an error, be it `AT+HTTPSSL=?` or `AT+HTTPSSL=1`...

Without this line, it works fine for HTTP requests but doesn't work with HTTPS urls.

This is the code I'm using:

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","www"
OK
AT+SAPBR =1,1
OK
AT+SAPBR=2,1
+SAPBR: 1,1,"xx.xx.xx.xx"

OK
AT+HTTPINIT
OK

AT+HTTPSSL=1         <-- this keeps on giving ERROR
ERROR

AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://my-api-url/xxx/yyy/zzz"
OK
AT+HTTPACTION=0
OK

+HTTPACTION:0,200,1819

AT+HTTPREAD
+HTTPREAD:1819
....CONTENT.....
OK

AT+HTTPTERM
OK
```

BTW, I'm using a Vodafone sim

Answer (score 2):

If you get ERROR issuing `AT+HTTPSSL=?` (which is the test command, that should answer with the range of the parameters), I'm afraid that specific command is not supported in your particular module.

You can check this also issuing `AT+CMEE=2` before 'AT+HTTPSSL=1', in order to enable verbose errors.

If you are sure that the module variant you are using does support SSL, verify that the FW version your module is running (check it by issuing `AT+CMGR` command) is the most recent one (you should find it out consulting the vendor site).

Comment: The module doesn't support ssl is weird....I even tried it with another module I have (Sim900a mini). It's the same. Even after `AT+CMEE=2` it just gives `ERROR`

Comment: Usually it means that command is unsupported at all. Not even recognized as a command by their parser, so that execution doesn't reach the section in which verbose errors are managed. Try issuing `AT+CLAC`: this command shows the list of all supported commands.

Comment: I tried that. It's not showing the SSL command. I've tried flashing 3-4 different firmware for sim900a, but none of them seem to support this. Do you have any idea which one can ?? byw, the module has 32M memory